# R: Iteratively applying a function via data.table mutate()

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table with the 2 million of rows that contain the following data:

- timestamp (epoch-seconds)
- duration (seconds)

What I'd like to do is convert that pair (timestamp, duration) into a vector (partial_0, ..., partial_k) where the partial_i's are the the range [timestamp, timestamp+duration) partitioned by minute boundaries. (A minute boundary is denoted by `timestamp %% 60 == 0`.

As an example, consider the data being:

```
timestamp duration
1:       100       90
2:       101       90
3:       110       60
4:       110       30
5:       120       20
```

The result of `split_window(timestamp, duration)` would be:

```
(20,60,10)
(19,60,11)
(10,50)
(10,20)
(20)
```

Here's `split_window`:

```
split_window <- function(timestamp, duration) {
  v = vector(,2+floor(duration/60)) # for result, so we don't keep copying it over
  i = 1
  while (duration > 0) {
    m = 60 - (timestamp %% 60)
    if (m > duration) m = duration
    v[i] = m
    i = i+1
    duration = duration - m
    timestamp = timestamp + m
  }
  v[1:i-1]
}
```

The good news is that `split_window` works. The bad news is I can't apply it to my table by doing:

```
t %>% mutate(splits=split_window(timestamp,duration))
```

`mutate` presents both timestamp and duration as vectors instead of iterating over the vectors.

What should I be doing instead?

Also, feel free to "fix" split_window to be more idiomatic R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `Map`:

```
dat = data.table(timestamp=c(100,101,110,110,120),
                 duration=c(90,90,60,30,20))

f = function(time,dur) {
  a = ceiling(time/60)
  b = floor((time + dur)/60)

  partials = diff(c(time, if (a <= b) (a:b)*60, time+dur))
  partials[partials > 0]
}

dat[, partials:= Map(f, timestamp, duration)]

> dat
#    timestamp duration partials
# 1:       100       90 20,60,10
# 2:       101       90 19,60,11
# 3:       110       60    10,50
# 4:       110       30    10,20
# 5:       120       20       20
```

Comment: Thanks @sirallen. I didn't know about `diff` and though I'm familiar with map() operations in other languages, I didn't know about it in R.

Comment: For clarity, `a` is the first minute boundary in the range, `b` is the last minute boundary in the range, and `c(time, if (a <=b) (a:b)*60, time+dur)` creates a sequence of `(time, a, a+60, ..., b, time+dur)` which is a list of boundaries.

Turns out that's actually what I want and was going to figure that out next, so thanks for answering 2 questions in 1 :D

Comment: Glad I could help!